# Changing value of attribute of QgsFeature using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, editing, features

I would like to update one attribute of a feature. However, I don't know to update it using the feature object. I have to use a data provider to update it.

```py
layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('my_line') 
layer = layers[0]
dp = layer.dataProvider()
it = dp.getFeatures()

for i in range(0, dp.featureCount()):
    feat = it.next()
    attrs = { 2 : 30 }
    layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({ feat.id() : attrs })
```

Can I change the value of an attribute using `QgsFeature` object?

Moreover, is it possible to loop using an iterator object?

Comment: how can I change values without using the index? I would like to change the values by naming their fieldname. That would be much more comfortable. Thank you very much! Greetings Robert

Comment: Simply use `my_index = layer.fieldNameIndex("my_field_name")` to get the index.

Comment: in this case i cant add in the field the string
how i can do?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/133393)

Comment: Hamed, Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange! Since this question has already been answered, please ask your question as a new, separate question here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Answering your two questions:

1. You can change your feature values from the `layer` object, no need to access the `dataProvider()`.
2. Yes, you can use the iterator in a `for` loop (that's what iterators are for :) ).

### Using `layer.changeAttributeValue()`

`changeAttributeValue()` is handy when you want to change the value of a single field for your features. For instance, let's see how to modify a single field for selected features:

```
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('my_line') 
layer = layers[0]  # We assume there is at least 1

field_idx = layer.fields().indexOf('my_field_name')
new_value = 30

with edit(layer):
    for feat_id in layer.selectedFeatureIds():
       layer.changeAttributeValue(feat_id, field_idx, new_value)
```

Which updates the field value to 30 for selected features.

---

If you want to update the field value for all features in your layer, do something like this:

```
with edit(layer):
    for feat in layer.getFeatures():
       layer.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(), field_idx, new_value)
```

Which updates the field value to 30 for all layer features. See [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/411054/4972) for optimizing the `getFeatures()` method.

### Regarding `layer.updateFeature()`

Always try to avoid the `QgsVectorLayer.updateFeature()` method. It's less efficient than `changeAttributeValue()`.

From [the docs](https://qgis.org/api/3.16/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a9334033354a994132b28fcd1700b64e3):

> This method needs to query the underlying data provider to fetch the
> feature with matching QgsFeature::id() on every call. Depending on the
> underlying data source this can be slow to execute. Consider using the
> more efficient changeAttributeValue() or changeGeometry() methods
> instead.

Answer (score 7):

To update a feature in PyQGIS, you can use the attribute name, as in `feature['state'] = 'DONE'`, instead of the field index. It is much more readable.

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
features = layer.getFeatures()

for feature in features:
    if feature['state'] == 'READY':
        with edit(layer):
            feature['state'] = 'DONE'
            layer.updateFeature(feature)
```

If you prefer to use the field index, you can get it with:

```py
fields = layer.fields()
idx = fields.indexFromName('state')
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, but you have to know the index of the field:

```
QgsFeature::setAttribute(int field,const QVariant & attr )
```

You can get the fields using `QgsFeature::fields` and then iterate through them until you find the one you want or `QgsFeature::attribute(const QString & name  )` to find the field index by name.

The reason for QVariant is that the setAttribute can take Integer, Float, Date and Text types. QgsFeature.attribute(name) returns a variant also of type int if the attribute is found and something else if it can't be found.. be aware of this in your code. A try..except block would be warranted, try to convert to int and except if type is not int.

It is possible that your feature doesn't support this method. Another method that I have employed is `QgsVectorLayer::changeAttributeValue`:

```
self.canvas.currentLayer().changeAttributeValue(UpdateFeatureID,FieldToUpdate,self.CurrentWidget.text(),True)
```

This tells the layer to update a specific feature and specific attribute. In the example case the value comes from a widget.

Comment: I tried `feat.setAttribute(1, QVariant(20))` but the system said _TypeError: PyQt4.QtCore.QVariant represents a mapped type and cannot be instantiated_

Comment: feat.setAttribute(1, 20) is how I've done it before. That is put the value '20' into attribute 1.

Comment: I tried `feat.setAttribute(1, 20)` but the values don't change.  However, I can `print(feat.attributes()[1])`

Comment: See edits, perhaps you have to call the QgsVectorLayer.changeAttributeValue which should use the driver to make the changes.