# Getting Polyline (Linestring) coordinates from line layer in QGIS

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis, pyqgis-3, linestring, polyline-creation

I have a [road network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKB4q.png) (line layer). I am trying to get list of coordinates (Lat,Long) from road network in the form of geometry LINESTRING as shown below. However, I am only getting two coordinates as shown in second figure.

[image]

What I have tried:

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer()
fl = ['lat','lon'] #Add these fields before executing code

with edit(lyr):
    for f in lyr.getFeatures():
        p = f.geometry().centroid().asPoint()
        _=f.setAttribute(f.fields().indexFromName(fl[0]), p.y())
        _=f.setAttribute(f.fields().indexFromName(fl[1]), p.x())
        _=lyr.updateFeature(f)
```

[image]

Comment: Well, since you're returning the centroid of the line, it's no surprise you only get point coordinates.

Comment: You use centroid's coordinates.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you try to achieve, but I think the '.asWkt()' function would be helpful:

for f in lyr.getFeatures():
    print(f.aswkt())

Comment: @Erik. What is the best way to extract coordinates(Lat,Long) from line layer?

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz. What are the other options please?

Comment: @Sam. Instead of print, can we save Wkt()' function coordinates in the line layer?

Comment: @CaseMsee You mean to store it as an attribute? sure! I recently used [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102119/how-to-change-the-value-of-an-attribute-using-qgsfeature-in-pyqgis) question to edit a feature's attributes. You can create a new string attribute and edit it with the value of "f.geometry().asWkt()"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, add a field (name: `geometry`, type: `string`, length: `1000` keep it long). Then use the following script:

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer()

with edit(lyr):
    for f in lyr.getFeatures():
        f["geometry"] = f.geometry().asWkt()
        lyr.updateFeature(f)
```

Comment: Great answer. The only thing is: the above code produces  MULTILINESTRING geometry in the attribute table. Is it possible to convert MULTILINESTRING to LINESTRING as shown in first image of question?

Comment: Your layer probably contains multilinestrings. Use `Convert geometry type` tool in `Processing Toolbox` to convert to `Linestring` before.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was thingking. Is it possible to plot MULTILINESTRING coordinates in the QGIS? Mapping XY coordinates are simple but I was wondering about  MULTILINESTRING coordinates

Comment: You can ask another question about it. **QuickWKT** plugin may help. I don't understand what exactly you mean.

Comment: Only an advice: I wrote the same but instead "geometry" I wrote 'geometry' and it has worked!

Comment: @PauloMatiasMontecinosMedel Typically, either single or double quotes can be used interchangeably in Python.