# PyQGIS is working too slow. Can I use GeoPandas?

Tags: python, pyqgis, geopandas

I have a layer with classification od buildings. I want to add "Area" to my attributes table and I use PyQGIS. For another layer with 50 records it works, but my layer is huge, contains 6.8mln record and it is working too slow. With another problem I used GeoPandas which is working so fast. I will paste my code and I need advice. Can I do it with GeoPandas?

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import *
from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant
from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsProcessingFeedback, QgsRasterLayer
import sys
import geopandas


sys.path.append('/usr/lib/qgis')
sys.path.append('/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins')
os.environ["QT_QPA_PLATFORM"] = "offscreen"


QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r'/usr/bin/qgis', True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()


import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing


Processing.initialize()
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())
feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()


#adding the Area field
layer = QgsVectorLayer(r'/home/gis/polskagisencoding.shp', "polskagisencoding", "ogr")
provider = layer.dataProvider()
area_field = QgsField("Area", QVariant.Int)
provider.addAttributes([area_field])
layer.updateFields()


#updating the Area field for each feature
idx = provider.fieldNameIndex('Area')
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    attrs = {idx : int(feature.geometry().area())}
    layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({feature.id() : attrs})
```

Comment: Have you tested to, instead of working on a shapefile, copy it into a memory layer. A memory layer is loaded entirely in memory and it's faster. If you create a GeoDataFrame, it's like a memory layer and you can yes, update features.

Comment: Examples in https://data.library.virginia.edu/how-to-use-the-field-calculator-in-python-for-qgis-3/ do it in different way. Also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102119/how-to-change-the-value-of-an-attribute-using-qgsfeature-in-pyqgis is updating layer, not dataProvider. Perhaps your code does something sub-optimal with the shapefile 6.8 million times and the bottleneck is not pyqgis but how it is used.

Comment: Why not put the data into a database like postgis and do the work there? Safer and almost certainly faster

Comment: Maybe yes, but I use Elasticsearch and I will not use another database system :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/)

```
import geopandas as gpd
gdf = gpd.read_file('/home/gis/polskagisencoding.shp')
gdf["Area"] = gdf.geometry.area
```

But I'm not sure it's faster with larger shapefiles

Comment: didn't work. Could you edit your comment?

Comment: It works without problem with a polygon shapefile. What is the error ?

Comment: It has returned Area = 0 for all records.

Comment: Try  `gdf["Area"] = gdf.geometry.area.astype(float)`

Comment: The same, has returned 0.

Comment: So I don't understand without the original data, are they polygons, multipolygons ?

Comment: They are polygons. If I use qgis it works, code is above

Answer (score 5):

For large datasets like this, you may want to use `dask-geopandas`. It is still under development (no official release yet) but `area` should work flawlessly.

You should install `geopandas`, `dask` and `pygeos` and then `dask-geopandas` from git.

```py
pip install git+git://github.com/jsignell/dask-geopandas.git
```

Then you can read your file with `geopandas` and convert it to `dask.dataframe`.

```py
import geopandas
import dask_geopandas

df = geopandas.read_file('/home/gis/polskagisencoding.shp')

ddf = dask_geopandas.from_geopandas(df, npartitions=4)

areas = ddf.geometry.area.compute()
```

`npartitions` in this case should be the number of processors you want to use. `dask-geopandas` then does the computation in parallel.

See more here https://github.com/jsignell/dask-geopandas

Comment: I use Ubuntu console and I don't have anaconda.

Comment: I haven't mentioned anaconda. You don't need anaconda, you can install all via pip.

Comment: didn't work, I got 0 for all records.