# QGIS Python update field crashes when in for loop

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I'm following the [cookbook tutorial](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/expressions.html#evaluating-expressions) on evaluating expressions. QGIS 3.16 using the in-built python editor. I've initiated the context scope in the variable `context` as per the tutorial. The rest is test code ultimately aiming at updating the double field `Rain_D` using the contents of the string field `Rainfall`

```
# Calculate Rain_D values

context = QgsExpressionContext()
context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(weather_l))

n = 0
with edit(weather_l):
    for fea in weather_l.getFeatures():
        n += 1
        context.setFeature(fea)
        if fea['Rainfall'].isalpha():
            print(n)
        weather_l.updateFeature(fea)
```

The problem is that when the `for` loop gets to about a thousand or so iterations (it's different every time) QGIS crashes. Any idea what's going on here? It works if I `break` after a few iterations, but not when going through the 100,000 or so records in `weather_l`.

Comment: This looks like a bug report. Have you considered creating an issue to inform QGIS devs? You can do so at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/ BTW, you can find some alternatives [in this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102119/how-to-change-the-value-of-an-attribute-using-qgsfeature-in-pyqgis/133669#133669).

Comment: I thought it was possibly a bug but I'm new at pyqgis so I wanted to check first. I'll submit it. Thanks.