# Update multiple attributes with QgsExpression using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

UPDATE
In the code it needs to be `f[realV]` , so:

```
    with edit(lyr):
        for f in lyr.selectedFeatures():
            f[realV] = QgsExpression(str(doString))
```

---

I would like to update multiple features and multiple attributes with values, which are in the same layer. However, with the following code, nothing happens, I not even get an error message and so I don't know, why the features do not update.

This is my code:

```
# string values, in the form of decimals like '13.777'
fieldnames = [
                'MD_str',
                'MN_str',
                'ME_str',

                'PL1D_str',
                'PL1N_str',
                'PL1E_str',

                'PL2D_str',
                'PL2N_str',
                'PL2E_str'
                ]


# empty fields of type 'real'
real_fields = [
    'MD_r',
    'MN_r',
    'ME_r',

    'PL1D_r',
    'PL1N_r',
    'PL1E_r',

    'PL2D_r',
    'PL2N_r',
    'PL2E_r'
]

# Create tuple
dict_real =  list(zip(real_fields, fieldnames))

for pair in dict_real:
    realV = pair[0]
    strV = pair[1]
    
    doString = f"to_real(\"{strV}\")"

    with edit(lyr):
        for f in lyr.selectedFeatures():
            realV = QgsExpression(str(doString)) # correction:f[realV]
            lyr.updateFeature(f)
```

Does someone know, what I'm not doing correctly?

Comment: You are creating a QgsExpression but you never evaluate it. Also you never try to set any attribute value. Check https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.22/core/QgsExpression.html and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/403397/51035

Comment: I just have found the error. It needs to be ``` f[realV] = qgsExpression(str(doString))```. Oh boy ... I worked on this quite a while. Probably its the very hot weather here today.

Comment: @bugmenot123 Thank you for trying to help me! But I must say, I did not quite understand your answer. What do you mean by 'evaluating the QgsExpression' and 'never try to set any attribute value'?

Answer (score 1):

I had the chance to actually update my code and try it out.
First of all, you need to know that it is not possible to transform a variable to another data type, for example from string to integer(see here: [PyQGIS: Convert string variable to number format WITHOUT creating a new variable](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/462168/pyqgis-convert-string-variable-to-number-format-without-creating-a-new-variable/462176#462176)).

So you will always have two variables in the end, one string one numeric.
Most importantly, I do not even need to use QgisExpression, but a simple equal was doing the job.

Steps to update multiple attributes are as follows:

1. Create new ('empty') columns of the type you need the new variable in, e.g. into type integer. As I have multiple columns I first create a list of fieldnames by adding '_n' (for 'new') to the names of the fields I want to convert to another data type.

```
# First create names for the new fields by adding '_n' to the fieldnames
# you want to convert
 
fieldsToConvert = ['fn1','fn2', ... ]
fieldsNEW = [name + '_n' for name in fieldsStr] # 'fn1' will be 'fn1_n'
```

2. Create new fields with the just created new names and specify the datatype you want the new variables to be in. Here, the new columns are of datatype integer (QVariant.Int)

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer()
lyr.startEditing()
for name in fieldsNEW:
     lyr.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField(name, QVariant.Int)])
     lyr.updateFields()
```

3. I then create a dict with tuples of strings, in which each tuple contains the name of the variable which should be converted and the name of the corresponding new variable.

```
dict_fields = list(zip(fieldsToConvert, fieldsNEW)) # creates :[('fn1','fn1_n'),('fn2','fn2_n'), ... ]
```

4. Update the fields by iterating over the dict and over the features.
   If you have a lot of features, there are other, more performant techniques than iterating and updating each feature.

```
# Iterate the dict of fieldnames
for pair in dict_fields:
    oldV = pair[0]
    newV = pair[1]

    # Put the active layer in edit mode and update the features
    with edit(lyr):
        for f in lyr.getFeatures():
            f[newV] = f[oldV]
            lyr.updateFeature(f)
```