# Converting string variable to number format without creating new variable using Field Calculator in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, fields-attributes, create

I have many variables which are of type string but contain in fact numbers.
In QGIS you can convert those strings to numbers by creating a new variable with the wanted numeric type (e.g. integer or real etc) and then just update the attribute using the Field Calculator as shown in the image (the variable 'PL1D_r' is an empty attribute of type 'real', the variable 'PL1D_str' is of type string).

However, this always requires to first create a new additional variable. So you always end up with two variables, for each variable you want to convert.

Is there a way to do this for multiple attributes 'in place', so really 'transform' the relevant string-variable to a numeric data type within QGIS?

[image]

Comment: To clarify, by "variable" are you referring to a field? Furthermore, your question title specifies PyQGIS but your question appears to be about the Field Calculator.

Comment: Hi @Matt, yes, I refer to fields when I say 'variable'. I'm always a bit confused, as a field may also be an attribute, a column ... 
I just refer to the field calculator, as I wanted to provide more background information, so how to do it in QGIS manually, per single field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot change the type of field. This is simply not possible.

But you could create a new field and delete the old one.

Another option is to create a new layer, a copy of your original layer, with the same fields, but different field types. If you want to do this, I suggest the ["Refactor fields"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#refactor-fields) tool in the Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).